# Need help in saving images using cropIwa

Tags: java, android

I added a destination file to save my images in app's created folder.

```
static final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appDirectoryName);
```

In [cropIwa's documentation](https://github.com/steelkiwi/cropiwa#image-saving), it needs destinationUri

Here is what I have done:

```
cropIwaView.crop(new CropIwaSaveConfig.Builder(Uri.fromFile(imageRoot.getAbsoluteFile()))
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                .setQuality(100) //Hint for lossy compression formats
                .build());
```

ADDED @Khaled Lela

```
cropIwaView.crop(new CropIwaSaveConfig.Builder(getUriFromFile(this, new File(R.xml.file_paths + ".png")))
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                .setQuality(100) //Hint for lossy compression formats
                .build());
```

ADDED @Khaled Lela a saveCompleteListener of cropiwa.

```
cropIwaView.setCropSaveCompleteListener(new CropIwaView.CropSaveCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCroppedRegionSaved(Uri bitmapUri) {
                addPicToGallery(CropProfilePicture.this, bitmapUri);
                Toast.makeText(CropProfilePicture.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Khaled Lela it gives me an error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create temp file where the image should save**

```
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile(context);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        Timber.e("Can't create photoFile:%s",ex.getMessage());
    }

private static File createImageFile(Context ctx) throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.US).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
}
```

**Generate `Uri` and use FileProvide when version LOLLIPOP or above**

```
  final Uri imageUri ;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile); // file://
    else
        imageUri = getUriFromFile(context,photoFile); // FileProvider
```

**Saving image logic**

```
cropIwaView.setCropSaveCompleteListener(bitmapUri -> {
  addPicToGallery(context, bitmapUri); // sendBroadcast to gallery to scan new added images...
 });

cropIwaView.crop(new CropIwaSaveConfig.Builder(imageUri)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                .setQuality(100) //Hint for lossy compression formats
                .build());
```

**Use `FileProvider` with android version LOLLIPOP and above**

```
private static Uri getUriFromFile(Context context, File newFile) {
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", newFile);
}
```

- Under app res add **file_paths.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.your_package_id/files/Pictures" />
  </paths>
  ```
- **manifest.xml**

  ```
  <application
   ...// other attributes 
   >

  <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="com.your_package_id.fileprovider"
      android:readPermission="com.your_package_id.fileprovider.READ"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
  </provider>

  </application>
  ```

  - **add permission**

    ```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ```

**Update**
Update image on gallery.

```
private static void addPicToGallery(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to setup file provider, I will update my answer new.

Comment: i added file_paths.xml under res and now it is in values directory. Also, I get an error: Element paths must be declared\n <paths> XML file should be in "xml", not values

Comment: Create folder under `res` with name `xml` then create `file_path` under that folder

Comment: Consider to change `com.your_package_id` with your app package id.

Comment: cropIwaView.crop(new CropIwaSaveConfig.Builder(getUriFromFile(this, new File(R.xml.file_paths + ".png")))
                    .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                    .setQuality(100) //Hint for lossy compression formats
                    .build());

Comment: new terms appears in front of me like photoFile and imageCallback.

Comment: updated my answer with extra details, please check and feedback,

Comment: error  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please ensure to change your `package id` one `file_paths.xml`.

Comment: yes i did what you said except the "Consider to change com.your_package_id with your app package id" i dont know where is it

Comment: found com.your_package_id in provider

Comment: it gives me a new error now Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.teameut.myapplication/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180806_131656_1455567069.png

Comment: Change package name  on `file_path.xml` like you did with `fileprovider`

Comment: it shows no error now but I dont seem to  see my crop image in my gallery?

Comment: i found the image now thanks. It doesnt need to be seen in my gallery. Thanks  a lot. You just saved 1 life. Spread Love.

Comment: Check my update for showing image in Gallery, `addPicToGallery`

Comment: thanks a lot brother. You are just amazing. Good day!

Comment: You are welcome!, imageUri to bitmapUri on crop callback.

Comment: bro, as I go back to try addPicToGallery method. There is no runtime error but it seems that I do not see the image to my gallery. Also, I added what I have done to my post.