# How to resolve "Access Denied" Error even after asking for permissions in run time

Tags: java, android, text-files, filewriter, access-denied

I am new to Android and i was trying to write a text file in the internal storage of the Android device.
But i am getting this exception.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Afile.txt (Permission
>   denied)

I try to narrow down the problem and i found that it's the problem of permissions so i use these permissions in the manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

But the problem was not solved then i found out that from higher versions than API Level 23 we've to ask for permissions during runtime so i used this function in runtime to ask for permission to write file in internal storage.

```
 private void checkDiskPermission ()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Has Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I called this function in button click event before writing the file.
And also used it in the

> onCreate

method separately.

But i am still getting the "Access Denied" Error.

Please help me what should i do and how to solve this problem.

Here is the Code for writing the File in the internal storage.

I wanted to save it in any more obvious folder Like "Downloads or DCIM" to access it easily but could not found any method for that so I am writing this file in "data" folder.

```
try {
checkDiskPermission();
                    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                    if(!path.exists())
                    {
                        path.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File myfile = new File(path, "Afile.txt");

                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile);

                    writer.append("Hello This is sample test!");
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();

                    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    query.setText(path.toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    query.setText("Catch " + ex.toString());
                }
```

I am using this code in the onClick Method of a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all Operating Systems, each file/folder has ownership rights/permissions and based on the user trying to access it, it either allows or denies the user completely (shows as `Permission Denied`). The folder `/data/` is private folder owned by the Android system itself. Any app trying to access it will be denied, even if the Storage permission has been granted. Certain locations are allowed by the app to read from and write to. Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` instead of `Environment.getDataDirectory()`. Check internal and external file storage sections in the following link on how to do so: [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me how to use download folder in internal storage?

Comment: Just updated the answer to use the download folder. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: @ahasbini After android `LOLLIPOP` you may need to use FileProvider, Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700631/1283715) for more info.

Comment: @KhaledLela `FileProvider` is to access files stored in private locations and owned by other apps. Since the aim is to access public locations, `FileProvider` is unnecessary.

Comment: @ahasbini can you please upvote my question i don't know why someone down voted it.

Comment: @uniqueSolutions Yes I'd like to know the clarification too from the one who caused this. But please do mark this answer as accepted since it did solve ur problem eventually which the other answer(s) didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the folders and files in the result of the `checkDiskPermission`
not after it. Just cut the codes after calling `checkDiskPermission` and move them in this method below:

```
private void checkDiskPermission ()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
        else
        {
           accessFilesAndFolders();
        }
    }


     @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            //move the accessing files and creating folders all here.
              accessFilesAndFolders();

            }

    void accessFilesAndFolders(){
     try {
                            File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                            if(!path.exists())
                            {
                                path.mkdirs();
                            }
                            File myfile = new File(path, "Afile.txt");
            enter code here
                            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile);

                            writer.append("Hello This is sample test!");
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();

                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            query.setText(path.toString());
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            query.setText("Catch " + ex.toString());
                        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: where to call this method? `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: You  don't need to call it. It will get called after you call `checkDiskPermission();
` method

Comment: but it didn't. i tried and it's not working. only `else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Has Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }` This part of `checkDiskPermission();` is executing

Comment: Check my edited answer. Because you allowed the permission once, it will be saved in the application storage and never will be asked for the permission, but it you uninstall the app and install it again it will ask again.

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: It's the same. Access Denied. Please also check the @ahasbini answer maybe you'll get some hint.

Comment: Can you share your logcat? I will help if you do

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. It's solved. Actually, it was a problem of accessing a private folder that's why Access was denied. Thank you again.

Comment: I glad if that worked. If that helped please give me one score

Comment: Sure.can you please upvote my question i don't know why someone down voted it